# Error command 'msbuild' failed: None when Install BaseMap for Windows 10 64 bit

Tags: matplotlib, matplotlib-basemap

im so newbie in matplotlib, and i want to install basemap in my windows 64 bit laptop.
i use python 3.11.5 and i have just successfully:

1. install pyproj-3.3.1-cp311-cp311-win_amd64.whl
2. osgeo4w
3. in visual studio build tool, i install Desktop development with C++, then add individual component: a. Windows 10 SDK, and MSVC v.143

then when i install basemap-1.3.3-cp311-cp311-win_amd64.whl, i get this error as shown below

```
 error: command 'msbuild' failed: None
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for matplotlib
```

can you help me please?
Running setup.py clean for matplotlib
Failed to build matplotlib
ERROR: Could not build wheels for matplotlib, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects

Answer (score 1):

```
pip install basemap
```

Starting from basemap 1.3.0 we can install basemap precompiled wheels with pip.

Comment: You can mark your own reply as accepted answer if it has solved your issue.